# Converting android java project to android kotlin project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have decided a few weeks ago to start converting my existing app (I wrote it in java) to kotlin.
I converted only one activity and I wanted to check the functionality before I will move forward and change all of my classes. 
Unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: DaggerSearchComponent
```

This is how I resolve my dependencies with this activity, this code will be called from within the onCreate method:

**SearchActivity.kt**

```
 override fun resolveDependency() {
    DaggerSearchComponent.builder()
            .applicationComponent(applicationComponent)
            .searchModule(SearchModule(this))
            .build().inject(this)

}
```

**SearchComponent.java**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = SearchModule.class, dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class)
public interface SearchComponent {

    void inject(SearchActivity activity);

}
```

The component of this activity is still written with java, although I tried to convert it with kotlin but I got the same error.

I added kotlin plugin in my build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I did not find any other useful information except for adding kotlin plugin the app gradle file but it did not work for me.

When using dagger2 is it possible to use kotlin with java or should I need to convert every component/module into kotlin before testing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you added these dependencies in module gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$rootProject.dagger2Version" 
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
```

And add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

also to module level gradle.

Make changes in SearchComponent(Kotlin)

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = [SearchModule.class::class], dependencies = [ApplicationComponent::class])
interface SearchComponent {

    fun inject(application: Application)

}
```